# python dictionary and list: how to convert it?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this type of dictionary:

```
dic = {
'blahAA,
AA': [
    u'cat'
],
'blahBB,
BB': [
    u'dog',
    u'bird'
],
'blahCC,
CC': [
    u'fish',
    u'horse',
    u'elephant'
]
```

}

blahXX is internet link, with XX the id.
How to convert it to have a list like that:

```
list = [['cat AA'], ['dog bird BB'], ['fish horse elephant CC']]
```

*Optionnal:*
Ideally, I would like to display each element (cat, dog bird, etc) in a Gtk interface (combobox), without displaying XX, with the idea to find the correspondant internet adress at the selection:

Example:

```
cat --Gtk--> blahAA
dog bird --Gtk--> blahBB
fish horse elephant --Gtk--> blahCC
```

Is it possible?
Thanks

My actual code to display the results is:

```
choice = self.liste.get_active_text()   # choice from the user
for url in self.links:
    if id in url: 
         adress = url
self.champ.set_text(adress)             # adress display
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> [v + [k.rsplit(',')[-1]] for k, v in dic.items()]
[['dog', 'bird', 'BB'], ['cat', 'AA'], ['fish', 'horse', 'elephant', 'CC']]
```

I'm not really understand for what purpose you want to concatenate all values in each child list, but you can do it with `join` method of `str`:

```
>>> [' '.join(v + [k.rsplit(',')[-1]]) for k, v in dict.items()]
['dog bird BB', 'cat AA', 'fish horse elephant CC']
```

**Update:** if you want to remove `.html` part from those urls, you'd do something like

```
>>> [' '.join(v + [k[:-5].rsplit(',')[-1]]) for k, v in dict.items()]
```

`k[:-5]` returns a new string without last 5 characters (in our case `.html`).

Comment: Thanks, the second solution is what I want. I will try and tell you.

Comment: Just one thing: My result is ['dog bird BB.html', 'cat AA.html'] (you couln't know) but how to remove ".html" ?

Answer (score 3):

```
[' '.join(map(str, x[1] + x[0].split(',')[1:])) for x in dic.items()]

Out[115]: ['cat AA', 'fish horse elephant CC', 'dog bird BB']
```

(Advantage of map(str, seq) is that it won't throw `TypeError` exception if some element of the list is say `int` - you can't concatenate ints and strings in Python as it is strongly typed language, if still dynamically typed language)

Comment: The result is same as frostnational, except the "u". But displayed in the Gtk interface no difference. Thank you

Comment: u'...' is unicode string. you could use map(unicode, seq) if that's what you want. (or use P3+ where every string is unicode)

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [[" ".join(v + [k.rsplit(',')[-1]])] for k,v in dic.items()]
print list
```