# python list: delete last string of sublist

Tags: python, list

I have this type of list:

```
lst = [u'cat 1234', u'dog bird 5678', u'fish horse elephant 9012']
```

How can I to delete the last word of each string, to have:

```
result = ['cat', 'dog bird', 'fish horse elephant']
```

Edit: I've add the "u", unicode, I don't know if thre's a difference 
Edit 2: Sorry for the faults, it hurts my eyes..

Comment: The last element of each sublist is *the whole string*...

Comment: This is a very easy answer that only requires you to iterate the list and slice the string. It's ridiculous that you're asking someone else to waste their time to explain it.

Comment: Yes you're right... I will rewrite my question !

Comment: @Guillaume Delete the question, do it yourself, and ask a better question later, if needed.

Comment: You are basically asking: how can I remove the last word in a string, and a separate other question: how can I apply an operation to a list of lists with just one element in each? I'm sure you'd have found solutions to both those *smaller* problems.

Comment: Why didn't you keep it like it was in your previous question?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I need both lists, lst and result. For the question, I can modify it. @frostnational: this question is the second part ! @All: I modify my question because your both code return: `[[''], [''], [''], ['']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
>>> [' '.join(x.split()[:-1]) for x in lst]
['cat', 'dog bird', 'fish horse elephant']
```

But I still can't understand why you want `list` elements to be concatenated. Looks like it gives you no advantages (considering your previous question [python dictionary and list: how to convert it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695763/python-dictionary-and-list-how-to-convert-it)).

Comment: Yeahhhh !! This code is working :) Thanks a lot ! Sorry for my weirds questions...

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to remove the last *word* from each nested string, use `str.rpartition()` or `str.rsplit()`:

```
result = [[val[0].rpartition(' ')[0]] for val in lst]
```

or

```
result = [[val[0].rsplit(None, 1)[0]] for val in lst]
```

The latter can handle strings delimited with more than just 1 space.

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [[u'cat 1234'], [u'dog bird 5678'], [u'fish horse elephant 9012']]
>>> [[val[0].rpartition(' ')[0]] for val in lst]
[[u'cat'], [u'dog bird'], [u'fish horse elephant']]
>>> [[val[0].rsplit(None, 1)[0]] for val in lst]
[[u'cat'], [u'dog bird'], [u'fish horse elephant']]
```

If your strings are *not* nested inside lists, then we don't have to unwrap and rewrap; the `[0]` indexing can go, as well as creating a new nested list:

```
result = [val.rpartition(' ')[0] for val in lst]
```

or

```
result = [val.rsplit(None, 1)[0] for val in lst]
```

Comment: I have a problem with your code:`>>> lst = [u'Fare maohi 102152859', u'Clips 102890631', u'T.N.T. 103216774', u'Via cultura "L\'Ochju, le Mauvais oeil" 101959892']
>>> [[val[0].rpartition(' ')[0]] for val in lst]
result = [[u''], [u''], [u''], [u'']]`

Comment: @Guillaume: That's because that is **not** a list of nested lists!

Comment: @Guillaume: why did you ask a question about a different data structure? For that structure the answer is `[val.rpartition(' ') for val in lst]`.

Comment: Your both lasts codes are working, my question was ugly.. thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string on the whitespace, and it gives you a list of words:

```
>>> s = 'fish horse elephant 9012'
>>> words = s.split()
>>> words
['fish', 'horse', 'elephant', '9012']
```

You can index a list to give everything except the last item using slicing:

```
>>> all_but_last = words[:-1]
>>> all_but_last
['fish', 'horse', 'elephant']
```

You can then join the list back together with a space separating:

```
>>> ' '.join(all_but_last)
'fish horse elephant'
```

So, you need to do this for each sentence in your list of sentences:

```
>>> [[' '.join(sentence.split()[:-1])] for sentence[0] in sentences]
[['cat'], ['dog bird'], ['fish horse elephant']]
```

Comment: Using either `str.rpartition()` or `str.rsplit()` means you don't have to split *everything*, then rejoin. All my code does is split on the last space and return the part without the last word.